Test if image is compliant to guideline
I am trying to build a model to determine if a product image is compliant (e.g. the image should have a ground, the image should not be placed at the edge of the image). The guideline is rather long, and there can be too many reasons that the image is not compliant, so it is not possible to tackle the uncompliant reasons one by one. I am looking for some how holistic solution.
Given the advance in image and text, I would imagine there are some readily available tools that can be used with minor fine-tuning. I appreciate if someone can offer some insight here.

if human workers had to do this task themselves, how would you explain to them what's "compliant"? -- why haven't you shown us any examples?
